How to disconnect MongoDB in Julia
Quick and simple question.
I have starting to use Mongoc.jl to implement MongoDB procedure into my Jetelina project.
I found "how to connect" in its manual, but nothing "how to disconnect".
I wonder MongoDB should not cut the connection in each?

No worries, the package does all that housekeeping for you.
The following code is from https://github.com/felipenoris/Mongoc.jl/blob/100b732c53d6ce50417dc93c86218c7f92629ed0/src/types.jl:
function Client(uri::URI)
    client_handle = mongoc_client_new_from_uri(uri.handle)
    @assert client_handle != C_NULL "Failed to create client handle from URI $(uri.uri)."
    client = Client(uri.uri, client_handle, nothing)
    finalizer(destroy!, client)
    return client
end

The Mongoc.jl package's Client struct represents a database connection. The finalizer (see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.finalizer) makes sure that when the client goes out of scope (or at the end of your program, if client is a global) the handle is closed.

Oh, thank you. I did not notice finalizer() was in there. :)

In the REPL if you want to force a disconnect for testing you can use the way that function works to see that destroy!(client) in REPL will disconnect client (and client will then not work).
